# When does SQL Server follow the Minimum Password Age policy?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, security, password, active-directory

According to [this SQL Server 2008 whitepaper](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&ved=0CD0QFjAF&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.microsoft.com%2Fdownload%2Fa%2Fc%2Fd%2Facd8e043-d69b-4f09-bc9e-4168b65aaa71%2FSQL2008SecurityOverviewforAdmins.docx&ei=jd3sVN3YCYLCsATlsYHgDQ&usg=AFQjCNFABHuZNZ4XL4nKZqrLaKFNFZ_X6A&sig2=h8dCedlkRykyc7dz9T-qkg&bvm=bv.86475890,d.cWc&cad=rja), SQL Server should only pay attention to the Minimum Password Age policy when the Check_Expiration (Enforce Password Expiration) option is turned on.  Page 7 in the whitepaper specifically says "CHECK_EXPIRATION uses the minimum and maximum password age part of the Windows Server 2003 policy, and CHECK_POLICY uses the other policy settings".  However, that's not what I'm finding.  It looks like you only need Check_Policy (Enforce Password Policy) turned on.

For example, I have a SQL Login (using SQL Server authentication) with Enforce Password Policy turned on, but Enforce Password Expiration turned OFF.  My domain's password policy has Minimum Password Age set to 1.  I can use sp_password to change the password once, but when I try to change it a second time, I get this error:

> Server: Msg 15114, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Password validation failed. The password for the user is too recent to change.

Is the documentation in this whitepaper simply wrong?  Why is this happening when Check_Expiration is off?  I also found [this site](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/922456) which also says that Minimum Password Age should only be enforced when Check_Expiration is on.  I think this is true for MAXIMUM Password Age, but I'm finding that Minimum Password Age is still getting enforced when Check_Expiration is off.

Is there something funky about my configuration?  Should Minimum Password Age really be enforced when Check_Expiration is off (but Check_Policy is on)?

Comment: I got the same on SQL Server 2019, one which I cannot administrate. Did you ever find out more?
Do you know what the minimum is?
Got your redirect from Stackoverflow, and then 0 answers here..